# How to update an xpath dynamically based on the value from workbook using python/selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, anaconda, spyder

I have to select any year depending on the year given in the excel sheet,for now i have given the year directly in code.Able to get the data written for city directly from the excel sheet and hard coding the year also works.The issue there are n number of years as links (not in drop downs)instead of writing xpath for each and every year,is there any way to get the value given from the excel sheet and place it the give xpath say "year".
Yearlink=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"year")]');
I am currently using spyder-python 3.7

Please find the code that i have tried

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome  
driver.fullscreen_window();
driver.get('url');
time.sleep(5) 
Workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("excel path")
Details = Workbook.sheet_by_index(0);
city=Details .cell(1,0)
Citytextbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="city"]');
Citytextbox.send_keys(city.value);
Yearlink=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"2000")]');
Yearlink.click();
time.sleep(10)
```

Update:Adding some part of html ,if there are any other methods do it also do let me know

```
<span _ngcontent-c26="" class="toggle link" ng-reflect-klass="toggle link" ng-reflect-ng-class="">

        1910

      </span>

    </li><li _ngcontent-c26="" class="option">

      <span _ngcontent-c26="" class="toggle link" ng-reflect-klass="toggle link" ng-reflect-ng-class="">

        1911

      </span>

    </li><li _ngcontent-c26="" class="option">

      <span _ngcontent-c26="" class="toggle link" ng-reflect-klass="toggle link" ng-reflect-ng-class="">

        1912

      </span>

    </li><li _ngcontent-c26="" class="option">

      <span _ngcontent-c26="" class="toggle link" ng-reflect-klass="toggle link" ng-reflect-ng-class="">

        1913

      </span>

    </li><li _ngcontent-c26="" class="option">

      <span _ngcontent-c26="" class="toggle link" ng-reflect-klass="toggle link" ng-reflect-ng-class="">

        1914

      </span>

    </li><li _ngcontent-c26="" class="option">

      <span _ngcontent-c26="" class="toggle link" ng-reflect-klass="toggle link" ng-reflect-ng-class="">

        1915

      </span>

    </li><li _ngcontent-c26="" class="option">

      <span _ngcontent-c26="" class="toggle link" ng-reflect-klass="toggle link" ng-reflect-ng-class="">

        1916

      </span>
```

**UPDATE**
When i try the below method i am getting this error.I am passing the value 1979 from excel,i am passing '1979 from excel if i don't add ' it takes it as numeric value.

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[normalize-space(.)='text:'1979''] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[normalize-space(.)='text:'1979'']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Excel image
  [image: Excel screenshots]

Comment: Can you share section of the html dom

Comment: @VardhmanPatil Added some part of the html,hope its enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution based on the suggestions provided.Have to add "Value" for the above solution to work

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("excel path")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
year_from_excel = sheet.cell(1, 1)
year_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalizespace(.)='{}']".format(year_from_excel.Value))
year_link.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

From a locator point of view you ideally want to do this:

```
year_from_excel = "2000"
year_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='{}']".format(year_from_excel))
```

This will result in the following path being used:

```
//span[normalize-space(.)='2000']
```

This is an XPath that will find a `<span>` element that has the text `2000`, however it will strip out all the surrounding whitespace when performing the comparison.

The next step is ensuring that `year_from_excel` is set to a value in your Excel spreadsheet.  Based on your existing code I'm going to go for:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("excel path")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
year_from_excel = sheet.cell(1, 1)
```

I do not have any insight as to how your Excel sheet is formatted though, so this may be wrong.  I have made the assumption that the year value is on the same row, but the next column along.

So if you stick all of this together, you get:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("excel path")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
year_from_excel = sheet.cell(1, 1)
year_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='{}']".format(year_from_excel))
year_link.click()
```

Comment: When i try the way you suggested i am getting an error,which i have updated above.Could you suggest what the issue might be.

Comment: It looks like `sheet.cell(1, 1)` is returning `text:'1979'` you could try `sheet.cell(1, 1).getStringCellValue()`

Comment: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'getStringCellValue' this issue is displayed ,i tried import wx.still no use

Comment: This implies that it should work https://github.com/youngrok/poi4py/blob/master/tests/test_excel.py